# Add a script trigger to Google Sheet that will work in Android mobile app: revisited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to implement the solution proposed by user79865 in this thread (which is closed and hence I opened this new question):

[https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/add-a-script-trigger-to-google-sheet-that-will-work-in-android-mobile-app][1]

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getW1Notation() == 'X1') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

*TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (Row 4, File "Makros")*

Row 4 is:

```
  if (e.range.getW1Notation() == 'X1') {
```

As Im a newbie I have no clue what is going on.

Thanx.

Comment: The referred Web Applications question is protected, not closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'X1') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      e.range.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Note: You can't run this function without supplying it an event object.

Comment: Ugh! En event object??? The original post didnt mention anything to that sort. Gotta figure out what that is... but Cooper am I asking something stupid when I ask: why did you leave out the statement:        `eval(e.value)();`   from your function above???

Comment: The event object is supplied by the simple trigger when a sheet is edited.  But none is supplied by you run from Script Editor.

Comment: where does the e in e.value come from?